# Navigation Includes Web Part Pages

Tags: office-365, navigation, publishing-site

My Drop down navigation is auto including web part pages. I'm looked through the navigation settings and I have had no luck in removing. Any assistance would be appreciated.[image: Screen Shot of my menus]

Answer (score 1):

You can change this behaviour using Site Navigation Settings

1. Open Site Settings
2. Click on Navigation
3. Uncheck "Show pages" from Global Navigation section
4. Click Ok

Comment: I thought that would resolve the issue, but I already checked that as well as the parent sites.

Comment: In the navigation settings page, can you see the tree view? You can use that to remove unwanted pages.

Comment: That works. However, I'd like to have that page listed on the left hand navigation.

Comment: I figured it out, if i add the link via the navigation settings instead of "Edit Links" on the left hand side, it works as expected.

Comment: You can use the Left Navigation section, enable Show Pages